# Using and installing libVlc or GStreamer for QT in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2017, gstreamer, libvlc, qtgstreamer

I would like to play an RSTP stream in Windows 10 using the QT Libraries in Visual Studio 2017.
Using DirectShowPlayer in QT Ctrator I have this error:

*DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x800c000d*

I found some code examples that use libVlc or QT-Gstreamer.

Unfortunately, I'm new to the world of QT and the logic of building libraries.
I don't know anything about cmake and related.
Does anyone know an easy step-by-step procedure to install and use these libraries (or even "generic" libraries examples)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this question is too vague, sorry. What have you tried on google before? which language are you using? You will probably need to learn about general cmake usage and SO is not adequate for this

Comment: I'm using Visual-studio 2017 (as specified in the tag). Now I've installed GStreamer and it'fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!
You need to download the VLC-QT binaries for your O.S. (e.g. Windows 64bit) and unzip them into the QT directory relative to the compiler in use (eg "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\msvc2017_64\") respecting the destination folders (eg bin, lib , includes).
Then you have to go in your project properties and add the VLCQtCore.lib, VLCQtQml.lib and VLCQtWidgets.lib libraries to the list of libraries (e.g. Project Properties-> Linker-> Input-> Additional Dependencies)